# Voice recognition and processing using a wireless microphone and a wireless speaker on RPi 3 B+

Tags: pi-3, wireless

I have installed Google Assistant on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and it seems to be working fine. My setup is:

1. The voice input is through a USB microphone.
2. The output is through the 3.5mm jack (I use a speaker or sometimes my earphone)

I had found an instructable which does the same:
https://www.instructables.com/id/Hands-Free-Google-Assistant-for-Raspberry-Pi/

But I wanted to modify this setup. I am just an amateur, so please guide me if I am wrong. Here it is:

1. I want my voice to be wirelessly transmitted to the RPi 3 using a wireless microphone and not just using a USB microphone.
2. And the output (Google assistant's response) must also be wirelessly transmitted to a speaker or my earphone.

(**This idea is just to make sure that we can have a hassle free experience, so that we can carry our RPi anywhere with us until we have an internet connection**)

I haven't tried it yet. But is it possible?

P.S: Please don't be rude. I am a beginner. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: wireless as in bluetooth ... or some wireless microphone that has a proprietary receiver (ditto for the speaker)

Comment: It can be bluetooth or a proprietary module too...

Comment: oh, so you haven't even got that far ... I'd go bluetooth, personally

Comment: Great. But is it possible?

Comment: Yes. But your question is a bit to broad, please read the FAQ on how to ask questions.

Comment: @MatsK Sorry if the question is too broad. But is there any possibility for the above situation.

Comment: yes, it is posible

Comment: Can you please explain? @Jaromanda X

Comment: you asked if it's possible, I said yes it is - now it's your turn to research